# Permutation: Number of ways 4 cars could park

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I came across this question in my Algebra textbook:

> Find the number of ways 4 cars could park right next to each other if the parking slots were:
>
> a) in a straight row
>
> b) in a circular form
>
> knowing that there are 10 parking slots available in total.

Here is my approach to solving the question:

a) There are 7 ways to begin with. Multiplying 7*4P4 or simply 7*4! should then be the answer.

b) I am not sure whether the point of beginning makes any difference here as the slots are circular so my guess is that the answer should be 1P1*3P3 or 3!

Am I right? 
Thanks!

Comment: Each car can be parked with its front facing outwards or inwards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Good work, your answer is correct.

(b) There are two possible interpretations of the problem; as you indicate, it's unclear whether or not the point of beginning matters, or in other words, whether any rotation of the cars around circle is the same.

- If the point of beginning does *not* matter, your answer of $3!$ is exactly right.
- If the point of beginning *does* matter, you would proceed similarly to (a), except there are $10$ possible points of beginning instead of $7$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your answer for b - second point, you mean if the beginning point does matter, right?

Comment: @Marlene In the second point, actually. Good catch, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

number of ways to arrange "r" cars next to each other in row in "n" places, you can use the formula
(n-r+1)*r!number of ways to arrange "r" cars next to each other in circle in "n" places, you can use the formula n*(r-1)!